# Read multiple lines from InputStreamReader (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, inputstream

I have an InputStreamReader object. I want to read multiple lines into a buffer/array using one function call (without crating a mass of string objects). Is there a simple way to do so?

Comment: are the number of lines you want to read in fixed or varied?

Comment: Fixed, say 100 lines each read

Comment: you may want to use nio to map a file into a bytebuffer (or charbuffer) if you are sensitive to garbage.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to create temporary Strings? Have you had a problem with memory usage?

Answer (score 3):

First of all mind that `InputStreamReader` is not so efficient, you should wrap it around a `BufferedReader` object for maximum performance.

Taken into account this you can do something like this:

```
public String readLines(InputStreamReader in)
{
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
  // you should estimate buffer size
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(5000);

  try
  {
    int linesPerRead = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < linesPerRead; ++i)
    {
      sb.append(br.readLine());
      // placing newlines back because readLine() removes them
      sb.append('\n');
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return sb.toString();
}
```

Mind that `readLine()` returns `null` is `EOF` is reached, so you should check and take care of it.

Comment: The objective in NOT to read line by lines, since it fills my heap with redundant string objects and makes the GC go wild. I wanted to read from an inputstreamreader (using a bufferedReader /whatever), without creating many String objects. Perhaps read directly into a buffer (without creating a string in the middle), or otherwise read multiple lines to avoid the string garbage...

Comment: what about using a __RandomAccessFile__ to read directly a buffer of bytes? Also the whole file (__readFull(byte[] b)__)

Comment: Strings are *very* optimized in JVM v. 1.6. Have you been using a profiler and really spotted an issue? Or are you just guessing?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some delimiter for multiple lines you can read that many characters using read method with length and offset. Otherwise using a StringBuilder for appending each line read by BufferedReader should work well for you without eating up too much temp memory